# I add heap size in Jmeter but still got OOM error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I run peak test in Jmeter, got OOM error, but when i add the heap size in Jmeter.bat file, it still got OOM error. My PC is RAM is 16G, updated the max heap to 8G. Below are my updated jmeter.bat file.

set HEAP=-Xms3g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=5120m

Answer (score 0):

[OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) can have many faces, it is not necessarily the lack of heap space, the other reasons could be in:

- [GC Overhead Limit Exceeded](https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) when the garbage collector is running and the program itself is not (or very slow)
- [Requested array size exceeds VM limit](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit) when you try to allocate too large objects
- [Unable to Create New Native Thread](https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshoot-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new) when it is not possible to create a thread due to underlying operating system limits
- etc.

Not knowing the details of your test plan and not seeing the full [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)) it is not possible to come up with the comprehensive answer, going forward consider including more details as "OOM" doesn't tell anything to us.

Comment: Dmitri, can you see my screen shot?

Comment: What screenshot? Are you running your test in GUI mode? If yes, it explains everything, you need to use GUI mode only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to execution you need to [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like `jmeter -n -t yourtest.jmx -l result.jtl`. Also make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm running in GUI mode. I also run with non-GUI mode, it can't complete the test, i need manually stop the procedure. So it still the heap size issue, right?

Comment: Sorry i edited your comment add screen shot on it, but it didn't show.